Issues After Upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04
I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu to 24.04, though this has seriously upgraded my waking of system and wifi, in which I had been facing problems recently, but there are few anomalies, Please help me with possible workarounds or should I report them to Ubuntu as a bug.

The system applications (settings, tweaks etc) don't show window buttons(like close, minimise and maximise) on being full screened, is it normal in 24.04?, how will i close it then without taking the application away from full screen and then closing.
The side bar in few applications is way too much then I think they should be(eg. tweaks, Endeavour) when not in full screen, Is it how the application is made as I am also not able to resize it vertically. Can I do it somehow??(Note: the sidebar width is perfect when the application is maximized to full screen, but otherwise the width of left sidebar increases very much).

Tweaks when not maximised
Endeavour when not max
Tweaks when max(Can also notice that window buttons are not present in full screen)

Some new applications are downloaded while I have the possible alternatives present,are they useful to keep

I had extension manager, now my system have extensions also.(both of them seems to do the same thing)
I had cheese(for accessing camera), now it has downloaded Camera app(though it is not able to connect to the camera somehow).
I don't know why but the upgrade has also installed KDE system settings, should I remove it?


In 22.04, which ever app was in focus, there showed a menu I should say on the left side of top bar with basic buttons like info, details, new window and most importantly quit which was quite handy for me, it is also not showing in 24.04, is that feature removed?

On opening Appearance section in settings, it is overriding the tweaks settings and changing the icon theme from vimix(which I prefer) to yaru-blue, then I have to revert back from tweaks to vimix again, it didn't use to occur in 22.04 where tweaks settings were the dominant and settings didn't clashed with it.



I have been able too fix most off the issues by myself, posting the answer for anyone else looking for solutions to the common issues. Any solutions for 5th issue are still welcomed.

The first and second issues were occurring as I had placed my window buttons to left, so the sidebar was getting enlarged when not maximized and not showing the buttons at all when maximized. Moving the window buttons to right from tweaks fixed the issue of enlarged sidebar and no buttons in maximized window.

As of the third issue, I couldn't find an explanation of why these extra applications are downloaded, and decided to remove them or keep some of them according to what I feel are necessary for my system.

In forth point, the App menu is removed from newer versions of Gnome, but can be brought back by using the 'App menu is back' extension.

The fifth point is not yet fixed, any workarounds are welcomed, I am avoiding to open that particular section in settings as of now to save me the trouble of reverting back to vimix again and again.



There is no 5 th issue in your post. Also This site only allows one issue per question.

@David He's referring to the 5th issue in the main question.
